# I want to extract the information from the text box and display it in message box without using Tkinter

Tags: python, qt, textbox, pyqt

I have created a UI using QT.

It had a textbox for the user to enter their name. Once if the user had pressed OK after entering his name in the text box, I need to display a Message box by showing the name of the user.
I tried to extract the information from the text box but I was not able to do it.

```
self._name=self._ui.lineEdit.get("1.0",END)
easygui.msgbox("Welcome !" + self._name, title="Greetings")
```

But the output displays `" PyQt4.QtGui.QtextEdit object at 0x02550C10 "`

Comment: Your title says TKinter, but you've mentioned and tagged this as QT. Which is is?

Comment: Without using Tkinter

Comment: Right sorry, misread the title completely. My bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
  nameStr = self.lineEdit.text()
  easygui.msgbox("Welcome !" + nameStr, title="Greetings")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of a [QLineEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html), you need to call [QLineEdit.text](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#text). Your code is just storing a reference to the QTextEdit, not the actual content.

Try this instead:

```
self._name=self._ui.lineEdit.text()
```

Comment: it says : "AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Yes, I edited that section out, I'm not sure why you had a `get` method call on there.